# ClickOnce + .NET client profile framework + SQL Server Compact + offline installation

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have issues with prerequisites while trying to publish my Windows .NET 3.5 application using ClickOnce.

I want my application to work offline as well as online, so I want to include the prerequisites in the installation and not make the client download them via the internet.

My prerequisites are:

- .NET Framework Client Profile
- [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) 3.5

I have downloaded the .NET Framework Client Profile Offline Installer. I installed it and put the `DotNetFx35Client.exe` in this location:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35Client
```

Under the Project - Publish Tab, I have checked the "Download prerequisites from the following location" and entered 
\MachineName\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35Client

Following
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046370?tab=oldest#tab-top

I, however, still the error:

> The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's website' file, Dotnetfx35client\Dotnetfx35clientSteup.exe'. In item .NET framework client profile can not be located on disk.

Answer (score 0):

First, just FYI, you can deploy the SQLCompact Edition by including the dll's rather than deploying the redistributable.

As for the .NET Framework Client Profile, I have no idea. I would have rolled a new package for the redistributable using the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator and included it with the deployment.

One thing you should know about the .NET 3.5 Client Profile -- if your customer has *any* version of .NET on the machine, it will install the whole .NET 3.5 SP-1. It actually only installs the Client Profile if the customer has *no* version of .NET on the machine. THey changed this in .NET 4.0, and the Client Profile is smaller too, so if you can migrate, you might want to consider it. It RTMs on Monday.

Comment: Are you sure that placing DLLs isn't a bad idea? This isn't C++ :) I suggest to install packages instead of 'raw' DLLs placing

Comment: Placing DDLs is a supported scenario with SQL Compact, and most of the engine is actually C++ DLL files.

Comment: Yes, it's supported. There's an MSDN article about it, if that makes you feel better. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(VS.80).aspx

You can pretty much do this with any dll that it will work with. For example, it works with DirectX, but not with Infragistics. Just depends on the asembly.