# Clickonce + .NET client profile 4 framework + offline

Tags: c#, clickonce, .net-client-profile

I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) project using Visual Studio 2010, and I am deploying using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce).

I need the application to work **offline** as well as online.

I have configured the prerequisite - .NET Client Profile 4 and set the location to the same as the application.

Everything seems to work as expected, but upon testing I have found it takes 5 minutes or more to install the .NET Client Profile 4 and it also requires a reboot.

Why does it take so long to install offline (I thought this was going to be mega fast like promised)?

And why does it require a reboot!?

Comment: Theres lots of registry changes and files that still need to be copied, my guess is that it is IO bound and will vary from computer to computer based on disk performance.

Comment: This question seems too similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604234/clickonce-net-client-profile-framework-sql-compact-offline-installation.

Comment: it depends on the windows version and which service pack, 5 minutes is Ok for the framework to setup, some computers with low rams, it takes more than an hour to finish

Answer (score 2):

5 minutes? You think 5 minutes is long? It took an hour to install .NET 3.5. I'd say 5 minutes is pretty darn good. It takes longer than that to install iTunes, dude.